# Collection View Segue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a collection view that will contain either one or two JSON parsed images that have been added to a mutable array.  I would like to segue from the collection view cell containing the image to another view controller. But,  the destination segue will contain a different image than the collection view(another JSON parsed image). Also, the two collection view cells will segue to different images. Summed up below:

Collectionview -------segue---------->         DesintationVC

Scenario 1

1. Objectatindex:0   imageA ------segue-----> newImageA

Scenario 2

1. Objectatindex:0   imageB ------segue-----> newImageB
2. Objectatindex:1   imageC ------segue-----> newImageC

What is the best way to go about this?

I was thinking along the lines of...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"image1"]) {
    if (sender == [pamphlet_Array objectAtIndex:0]){

    }
}
```

but,  not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one segue from your collection view controller to the detail view controller (let's call it `detailSegue`). You also need a tap gesture recognizer, just drag it in your collectionviewcontroller from the storyboard. Then create an IBAction related to this gesture recognizer (ctrl-drag it from the storyboard to your view controller's implementation, select UITapGestureRecognizer as the sender type and name it, say, `tapped`).
In this `tapped` method put something along the following code:

```
- (IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:tapLocation];
    if (indexPath) {
    self.pamphlet = [pamphlet_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]

        NSLog(@"Selected pamphlet: %@", self.pamphlet);

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Where `self.pamphlet` is a property of your collection view controller of type `Pamphlet*` (or whatever you store in the `pamphlet_Array`).

Then in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method just do something like:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
        YourDetailViewController* vc = (YourDetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController
        vc.selectedPamphlet = self.pamphlet;
    }
}
```

Now your detail view controller will be aware of what pamphlet was selected and therefore you can show whatever you need to show depending on that.

I hope this helps, let me know if it works!

Comment: I'd rather create a segue from the collection view cell to the next view controller (no tap gesture recognizer is needed afaik)